# VBA: Paste altering formula to #REF

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, sumifs

I have a problem whereby pasting a value into a particular cell alters a formula that uses that cell as an input. Hopefully below explains it better.

In my VBA code I first assign a formula to a particular cell, a SUMIF function looking at the data in columns F and G and using the cell A1 as its logical criteria:

```
dim CHECK as Worksheet

CHECK.Cells(1, 2).Activate
ActiveCell.Formula = "=sumif(F:F,A1,G:G)"
```

Next the code copies and pastes a value into cell A1 from a list in column E, which will be used to now update the formula:

```
CHECK.Cells(1,5).Cut
CHECK.Cells(1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

However, once the code is finished I find the formula in cell B1, ie cells(1,2), has changed to:

```
=sumif(F:F, #REF!, G:G)
```

I need the formula to be maintained regardless of what is pasted into cell A1. Is there anyway to sort this?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
CHECK.Cells(1,5).Copy
```

instead of:

```
CHECK.Cells(1,5).Cut
```